# Why does my site jump on first load?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just finishing off a site for someone and cannot work out why it jumps on first load. I thought it might have been a delay in loading a CSS file so have added some inline CSS to try to fix the issue, but can't figure this one out. Does anyone have any ideas?

![Demonstration example showing page jump][1]

[Live site][2] (you may need to force refresh the browser to see it - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the place to seek debugging help. If you have a question regarding specific code you might be able to get answers, but this is not an appropriate question.

Comment: MWD, you should include the relevant code in the question. Otherwise it may not be helpful for other people if your link die.

Comment: Silly moderation give stackoverflow a bad reputation - https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow+moderation+problems

Please be fair & make stackoverflow a good place like it used to be :)

Comment: Thanks for proving my point - negative comments are not helpful & make this site look bad. If you are unable to answer people questions please refrain from being negative.

Comment: BTW: There was nothing wrong with my question as it was answered correctly within minutes of me posting it. This site is meant to be about helping each other. If your unsure of the answer please just move on.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question. *"There was nothing wrong with my question as it was answered correctly"* - that is a false assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the jump is because the `<div id="header">` gets the class `.affix-top` with JavaScript and in the first load there is a small delay (for all JS to load).

I would suggest to add the class directly from the HTML.

**Edit**: If one looks at the documentation of [affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) component in Bootstrap you don't have to put the `.affix-top` in your code since it is added by the component.

> 1. To start, the plugin adds `.affix-top` to indicate the element is in its top-most position. At this point no CSS positioning is required.

But in this case the the addition of the class via code would cause the *jump* of the page's header due to a change in a `margin-top` value.

Comment: Glad I helped. Affix can be really tough to make it work sometimes. Since in worked, consider accepting my answer, thanks